# Route traffic based on source IP

Tags: linux, routing

I have two routers set up with different WAN IP's from different providers. Both routers have LAN IP's on the same subnet (10.2.2.x) and are connect to a switch. All hosts currently on the LAN subnet are connect to the same switch and have their default gateway set to router1. I'm trying to set up IP rules on a host to route traffic from router1 out on router1 LAN IP, and traffic from router2 out on router2 LAN IP. I pray to Cthulhu that makes sense.

I've been through source-based routing docs but can't find a scenario similar to mine. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Generically, this is called policy-based routing, which might get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @EEAA I've been through chapter 4 at lartc.org but the examples shown there don't quite apply for my setup. I'll continue searching for more info on policy-based routing.